# Python Using Find() Method with a List

Tags: python, list, replace, find

I am trying to use the find() method to find the zip codes in a list from text that has been scraped from a .PDF.  Below is an example of the text and my code so far.  I am able to get it to run without errors but it does not produce an output.  I would like to be able to use 'SOC' string to find the line that contains the city, state and zip then use the replace() method and replace the state with "" and also replace the zip with "".  The issue is that while the state will always be NY and can be established with a variable or string, the zip can be a number of different zip codes and I will not know what they will be in the scraped text.  Thus I was hoping to use the find() method to go through the text and be able to compare it to a list since I can enter them all in the list and just let the code replace what it finds.

```
Smith, Joel
Soc Sec#: xxx-xx-1111
56 Monroe Drive
Smithville, NY 14221
27

Smith, Nicole M
Soc Sec#: xxx-xx-2222
56 Monroe Dr
Smithville, NY 14226
25

    state = "NY"
    zip = ["14206", "14215", "14218", "14221", "14226"]
# Searches for City
    if line.find('Soc') != -1:
        if line.find(str(zip)) in zip != -1:
            print(lines[indx].strip().replace(state, "").replace(zip, ""))
```

Answer (score -1):

To find an element in list use `in` keyword. If the searched element is present in the list, it will return `True`,  else, it will return `False`.

[image: Image1]

Comment: The question is about using find(). Your code isn't doing that.